# Completion Handler True before completed

Tags: swift, xcode, completionhandler

so I have a function that gets a quote and author from an API. I have a completion handler so that i can get the quote and author and then set them to their respective UILabel in the Viewdidload function. But for some reason both the quote and author come up nil. What's going wrong with the handler?

```
    func getJSON(completionHandler: @escaping(CompletionHandler)){
    if let quoteURL = URL(string: "http://quotes.rest/qod.json")

    {
        let session = URLSession.shared


        let task = session.dataTask(with: quoteURL)
        { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if data != nil
            {
                let quoteData = JSON(data: data!)

                self.quote = quoteData["contents"]["quotes"][0]["quote"].stringValue
                self.author = quoteData["contents"]["quotes"][0]["author"].stringValue


            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
     completionHandler(true)
}
```

Calling the function in the Viewdidload()

```
        self.getJSON(completionHandler: {(success)-> Void in

        if(success){
            self.quoteLabel.text = "\(self.quote ?? "") - \(self.author ?? "")"
        }
    })
```

Swift doesn't allow you to set UILabel text in background processes which is why i cannot do it in getJSON()
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to insert it inside the callback

```
func getJSON(completionHandler: @escaping(CompletionHandler)){
    if let quoteURL = URL(string: "http://quotes.rest/qod.json") 
    {
        let session = URLSession.shared 
        let task = session.dataTask(with: quoteURL)
        { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if data != nil
            {
                let quoteData = JSON(data: data!)

                self.quote = quoteData["contents"]["quotes"][0]["quote"].stringValue
                self.author = quoteData["contents"]["quotes"][0]["author"].stringValue 

                completionHandler(true) // set it inside the callback
            }
            else {
                completionHandler(false)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    else {
         completionHandler(false)
    }
}
```